# Securing Azure API

Tags: azure-api-apps, azure-api-management

I have an Azure WebAPI and I have added it to Azure API Management.

As well as accessing the API through an API Management URI I note that I can still directly access the Azure API using the URI to the API.

In order to secure the raw API should I:

- add code to the API in order to secure it (by treating the API as the ASP.Net application it is and using a certificate)

or

- Use some facility of Azure to secure the API

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your choice.

- Upload a certificate to API Management, and verify it in your API
- Enable basic auth security in API Management and in your backend API
- Add a secret to a custom header in API Management and check it in your API.
- Check the inbound IP address in your API as an API Management instance will keep the same IP for as long as it is provisioned
- Add your API to an Azure VNet and use a network security group to only allow the API Management IP address access to the VNet